# Quartz force a message driven job to be non concurrent

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, quartz-scheduler

I have a quartz driven message driven bean:

```java
@MessageDriven(activationConfig={@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="cronTrigger", propertyValue="* * * * * ?")})
@ResourceAdapter(value="quartz-ra.rar")
public void SomeJob implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(final JobExecutionContext job) throws JobExecutionException() {}

}
```

Now I understand that if I change SomeJob to be a `StatefulJob` only one execution will happen at any single time. Each trigger will wait for the previous job to complete. This is what I require, I have seen that `StatefulJob` is deprecated and `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` is the replacement. Does this work with EJB dessage driven beans?

Another issue (may well deserve a new question), if my job is being triggered every second (as above), but sometimes takes a minute to execute what happens to the backlog of jobs. Is there a max size on the backlog, will this throw an error at some point? Is there a way of forcing jobs to get ignored if a job is currently being executed?

Answer (score -1):

I really can't understand what you're trying to accomplish?

A Quartz job is invoked when Quartz finds a trigger who's scheduled fire time has arrived.  Also, Quartz is the thing that instantiates the job instance (via the JobFactory interface).

A MessageDrivenBean is invoked when a message arrives in a JMS destination (that the bean is configured to consume from).  In this situation the EJB container is the thing that instantiates the class instance.

I don't understand how you're expecting to create something that is both at the same time?!?!?

Comment: You can drive a schedule using EJB MDB and the Quarts resource adapter http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/Quartz_scheduler_integration.html I am asking if this method honors @DisallowConcurrentExecution, and what happens to the backlog of "messages"/"jobs" and how is it stored ?